# Removing an item makes recyclerview to show first item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a `RecyclerView` and when I want to remove an item I call this:

```
Tipss.remove(position); //Tipss is my array
adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
rv.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My problem is that after I remove the view the `RecyclerView` goes all back to the beggining. I know that's because `rv.setAdapter(adapter)` is being called. If I remove that line the next view (the one after position) will have the height of the removed one and that just ruins the layout. Can someone help me here? `rv.setHasFixedSize()` doesn't work.

Comment: the whole point of the `adapter.notifyItem...` is so you dont have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` everytime which redraws eveything again

Comment: `setHasFixedSize()` doesn't work because they don't have a fixed site or `If I remove that line the next view (the one after position) will have the height of the removed one and that just ruins the layout` wouldn't happen. Try just using `notifyItemRemoved(position);` It should update for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two lines are not required

```
rv.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

If your recyclerView needs to have different properties based upon some conditions for each row, define then in your `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: But what should I do about the height resizing? I already mentioned in the question that if I remove the `rv.setAdapter(adapter)` the next view will have the removed view's weight.

Comment: did you try removing both lines and not just rv.setadapter()?

Comment: Yes, I tried everything. About you suggestion, the behavior is the same if I remove the adapter one or both.

Comment: Then maybe try once to have this combination:

Tipss.remove(position); //Tipss is my array
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: With that lines it still resize but don't go to the beggining. I want this to not resize and to not go to the beggining.